# How do I add a line number to a file?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

The contents of file.txt:

```
"16875170";"172";"50"
"11005137";"28";"39"
"16981017";"9347";"50"
"13771676";"13";"45"
"5865226";"963";"28"
```

File with the result:

```
"1";"16875170";"172";"50"
"2";"11005137";"28";"39"
"3";"16981017";"9347";"50"
"4";"13771676";"13";"45"
"5";"5865226";"963";"28"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`awk` can do this for you pretty easily.

```
$ cat test.txt
"16875170";"172";"50"
"11005137";"28";"39"
"16981017";"9347";"50"
"13771676";"13";"45"
"5865226";"963";"28"

$ awk '{print "\""NR"\";"$0}' test.txt
"1";"16875170";"172";"50"
"2";"11005137";"28";"39"
"3";"16981017";"9347";"50"
"4";"13771676";"13";"45"
"5";"5865226";"963";"28"
```

This tells awk to print a literal `"`, followed by the record number, followed by `";`, then rest of the line.  Depending on other needs not stated (e.g. the quoting not being totally necessary,) there may be a better method to use but given the question and output this works.

Grep solution for funsies:

```
$ grep ".*" test.txt -n | sed 's/\([0-9]*\):/"\1";/g;'
"1";"16875170";"172";"50"
"2";"11005137";"28";"39"
"3";"16981017";"9347";"50"
"4";"13771676";"13";"45"
"5";"5865226";"963";"28"
```

Comment: Nicely done; re funsies: `grep -F -n '' test.txt` is perhaps better; also note that `cat -n` can do numbering: `cat -n test.txt | sed -r 's/^ *([0-9]+)\t/"\1";/'`

Comment: When I need quotes in my awk script, I usually assign them to a variable, e.g.: `awk '{ print q NR q FS $0 }' FS=\; q=\"`

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of sed:

```
sed "=" test.txt | sed "N;s/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\n/\"\1\";/"
```

Output:

```
"1";"16875170";"172";"50"
"2";"11005137";"28";"39"
"3";"16981017";"9347";"50"
"4";"13771676";"13";"45"
"5";"5865226";"963";"28"
```

Answer (score 0):

also, bash-based:

`i=0; cat my_file.txt | while read line; do i=$(( $i + 1 )); echo \"$i\"\;"$line"; done > results.txt`

Comment: That works, but will be painfully slow except for small files.
Aside from that, I suggest using `< my_file.txt` after `done` rather than `cat my_file.txt |` before `while`.
A possible, though perhaps a tad obscure optimization is to replace the body of the loop with `echo "\"$((++i))\";$line";`

Answer (score 0):

There is also coreutils `nl`:

```
<file.txt nl -s';' -w1 | sed 's/[0-9]*/"&"/'
```

Or `perl`:

```
<file.txt perl -pne 's/^/"$.";/'
```

Or `sed` and `paste`:

```
<file.txt sed = | paste -d\; - - | sed 's/[0-9]*/"&"/'
```

Output in all cases:

```
"1";"16875170";"172";"50"
"2";"11005137";"28";"39"
"3";"16981017";"9347";"50"
"4";"13771676";"13";"45"
"5";"5865226";"963";"28"
```